# Linear Algebra Infinite dimensional bases

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$.

Suppose $V$ is the set of all inﬁnite sequences $a_0$$a_1$$a_2$..., such that in each sequence only finitely many of the components $a_i$ $\in K$; i = 0,1,2,... are nonzero. (Addition of two sequences is deﬁned component-wise).
 Show that $V$ is inﬁnite-dimensional and give an example of a basis in $V$ . Show that this will no longer be a basis if $V$ was the
space of all infinite sequences $a_0$$a_1$$a_2$..., with components in $K$.

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What part of this is giving you trouble?

Comment: I think a basis for this would be made of sequences S = {s$_i$: such that for i=1,2,... the ith component is 1} so then the first basis element is 10000000... But i don't then see how for all infinite sequences this can't be done, when in the first part although there there are only finitely many non-zero components, there are still infinitely many elements.

Comment: The original $V$ is a (proper) linear subspace of the second $V$.  How can a basis of a proper subspace be a basis of the whole space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of a (hamel) basis is that every element of the vector space can be written as a *finite* linear combination of the (hamel) basis elements.

In the case where there are finitely many non-zero components take the basis as $B=\{e_i\}_{i=0}^\infty$ where $e_i$ has $a_i=1$ and $a_j = 0$ for $j \neq i$.

Then, any element of $v \in V$ has non-zero indices $A$ and can be written as $\sum_{a \in A} v_a e_a$ (which is a finite sum, since $|A| < \infty$).

For the case where you can have any sequence in $K$, consider the all ones sequence, which cannot be written as a finite linear combination of elements of $B$.

Unrelated note: Every vector space has a Hamel basis (equivalent to axiom of choice), and for a finite dimensional vector space, every basis is a Hamel basis. However, for most infinite dimensional spaces, we can't write out an explicit Hamel basis, but we are free to use one in proofs by assuming its existence.